# How to call function from another ViewController

Tags: ios, function, swift2

I am trying to call a function `reloadTable` in my HomeViewController from my Task class. But I keep being thrown an

> Use of instance member 'reloadTable' on type 'HomeViewController'; did you mean to use a value of type 'HomeViewController' instead?

This is my HomeViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
 func reloadTable() {
    self.displayTask.reloadData()
}
}
```

This is my Tasks class:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
class Tasks {

static let sharedInstance = Tasks()

var datas: [JSON] = []

func getTaskDetails(){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, Data.weeklyEndpoint).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)

            if let buildings = json.array {
                for building in buildings {
                    if let startDate = building["start_date"].string{
                        print(startDate)
                    }
                    if let tasks = building["tasks"].array{

                        Tasks.sharedInstance.datas = tasks

                        HomeViewController.reloadTable()

                        for task in tasks {
                            if let taskName = task["task_name"].string {
                                print(taskName)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }

}

// for prevent from creating this class object
private init() { }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many of the other answers states, you are trying to access a non-static function on a static reference.

I would suggest the use of closures, consider the following;
Create a closure for `.Success` and the `.Failure`, this enables you to act accordingly to the data request result. The `onError` closure is defined as an optional, this means you don't have to implement the `onError` in the ´getTaskDetails` function call, implement it where you feel you need the error information.

```
func getTaskDetails(onCompletion: ([Task]) -> (), onError: ((NSError) -> ())? = nil) {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, Data.weeklyEndpoint).validate().responseJSON { 
        response in

        switch response.result {
            case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)

            if let buildings = json.array {
                for building in buildings {
                    if let startDate = building["start_date"].string{
                        print(startDate)
                    }
                    if let tasks = building["tasks"].array{

                        Tasks.sharedInstance.datas = tasks

                        onCompletion(tasks)
                    }
                }
            }

            case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            onError?(error)
        }
    }      
}
```

From your `HomeViewController`:

```
// Call from wherever you want to reload data.
func loadTasks(){

    // With error handling.
    // Fetch the tasks and reload data.
    Tasks.sharedInstance.getTaskDetails({
        tasks in

        self.displayTask.reloadData()
    }, onError: {
        error in

        // Handle error, display a message or something.
        print(error)
    })


    // Without error handling.
    // Fetch the tasks and reload data.
    Tasks.sharedInstance.getTaskDetails({
        tasks in

        self.displayTask.reloadData()
    })
}
```

[Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309)

[Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: Hi @Laffen why did you put onCompletion: ([Task]) -> () ? I'm not sure how that works

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at the `Closures` link i provided, the docs will explain in detail what/how and why. You define the `onCompletion` on your function you want to include a closure; You call the `onCompletion` from within that function, where the data requested is returned. When you call the ´getTaskDetails` you define the body of the `onCompletion`, this is where you tell the closure what to do when it's called from within the function it is defined. This got a bit hairy...

Answer (score 1):

In this case `reloadTable()` is an instance method. You can't call it by class name, you have to create object for `HomeViewController` and then you have to call that method by using that object.

But in this situation no need to call the method directly by using `HomeViewController` object. You can do this in another way by using `NSNotification`

Using `NSNotification` :

Add a notification observer for your `HomeViewController`

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(HomeViewController.reloadTable), name:"ReloadHomeTable", object: nil)`

Add the above lines in your `viewDidLoad` method of `HomeViewController`

Now replace this line `HomeViewController.reloadTable()` by `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ReloadHomeTable", object: nil)` in your `Task` class

Comment: Don't forget to remove the observer.

Comment: But i wonder where to remove the observer ? viewDidUnload is not available now. But some times we need to update the data even if the view disappeared.

Comment: When you want to remove the view controller from the stack, that's when you should remove the observers for that view. Inside the `dismissViewController(_:)` or something like that.

Comment: But how if we pushed the view and clicked on default back button ?

Comment: Okay, sorry.. It turns out iOS 9 came with some new features towards NSNotificationCenter; https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter

Answer (score 0):

Make class Task as Struct, make function getTaskDetails as static and try to call function getTaskDetails() in HomeViewController. In result this  of this function use realoadTable()

Answer (score -1):

In HomeViewController you have defined reloadTable() as instance method not the class function.You should call reloadTable() by making instance of HomeViewController as HomeViewController(). Replace

```
HomeViewController.showLeaderboard()
HomeViewController().showLeaderboard()
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding.

Comment: Haven't tried but logically Yes. Btw I personally prefer notification pattern in such cases over this.

Comment: it will not work, because view controller has one instance of HomeViewController, but when you call HomeViewController() it creates another instance and it is different from the viewCotroller's instance.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me with such a piece of information. :)

Comment: I tried it , every time showLeaderboard() is called new object of HomeViewController is created. Sry i slipped that concept while giving ans. @raki Thanks.